# Working of the Chain Rule in Calculus

Tags: differentiation, mathematics, calculus

I came across a proof of the **chain rule** in a book called "Calculus Made Easy" by Silvanus P. Thompson. It said that the rule works because we essentially **multiply and divide** by another small change in another function (usually represented as *du* for a change in function *u(x)*).

I.e.$$\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac {dy}{du}.\frac {du}{dx}$$

But when I tried to confirm this with my Physics teacher, he said that we can't actually explain it in that way because, *du* separated from *dy* or *dx* has no meaning as $\frac {d}{dx}$ is considered as a **whole entity** or an **operator** rather than a **fraction**. Please help me out with a clear explanation regarding this.

Also, please say whether there is any more **direct** approach other than the **indirect** (I suppose, it's indirect because we make up an intermediate function) chain rule to differentiate function compositions such as $$y=e^{sin x}$$

P.S. I'm just a beginner in the context of Calculus.

Comment: This is off-topic for physics. But a simple appropriate proof of the chain rule for your level can be found here: https://www2.math.uconn.edu/~stein/virtual/Notes/Calculus/chainrule.pdf

Comment: @MattHanson, I do not think this is off-topic in physics. Leibnitz's notation for derivatives is much more popular in Physics than in Math. Unfortunately, most physicists use this notation with a sense of guilt, thinking that it does not have a sound mathematical justification. I could write an answer justifying my claim, but I am tired of answering questions that are in the process of being closed.

Comment: Some chain rule proofs: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1180686/207316 BTW, there's no point migrating this question to Math.SE because it would be closed as a duplicate.